# Code mutation tools for Java

Tags: java, mutation

I am trying to find tools that mutate Java source code. I am looking for these tools in order to assess the effectiveness of automated debugging algorithms. To date, I have been manually injecting faults in programs in order to test these algorithms. I think mutation will be a nice way to automate this task.

So far, I have only been able to find Mutation Testing tools, like Pitest and Jester.
These tools, despite having the mutators I'm looking for, do not save the mutated source files, which is what I'm after. So, please, do not recommend me Mutation Testing tools that only mutate programs in-memory.

Are there such tools available?

Comment: Tool recommendation request are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins can you suggest a more suitable place?

Comment: Stack Exchange sites usually accept questions with specific, factual answers. Tool requests often opinion-based, and many answers will be equally valid. For this reason, I do not know of any Stack Exchange site that is suitable for your question.

Comment: I don't see this question as being off-topic. It's not a request for opinions about tools, just about their existence. It's not all that different from, say, asking about whether anyone knew about the availability of a compiler for the B language.

Comment: @Ted This is the text of the close reason: "_Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: @GeorgeCummins ted is saying that he is neither asking for a recommendation or for us to find anything specific for him; he's just asking for a yes or no.

Comment: @Justin, I understand. However, such requests are still off-topic. For more information, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125379/should-is-there-a-tool-that-questions-be-allowed) on Meta Stack Overflow, especially Robert Harvey's answer.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I'm not even sure if these tools exist. Of course I tried to search on google first. I have also explained my problem and stated what I am doing now to solve it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins - Interesting that you point to that discussion. It has two answers. The accepted answer states: _"Questions about software tools are acceptable, and I see no reason why this wouldn't include asking whether there's a tool that does X."_ Harvey's answer states: _"The only exceptions are questions that are narrow enough that they can be reasonably answered definitively with one or two possible solutions."_ It seems that the current question definitely falls into that category. If OP had asked about an "API" instead of a "tool", would that have put it in bounds in your view?

Comment: @Ted That would be a good question to ask on Meta.

Comment: I don't think this question is likely to attract "opinionated answers". The question is narrow and the number of tools in this space very limited. @aperez it is possible to modify pitest to store mutants to disk (compiled bytecode rather than source) - it has been used this way for various research purposes. If this would be of help ask a question at the pit user group for details.

Comment: @henry Thank you for your comment! I have just now started a topic about this in the pit user group. Hopefully I will get more help there.